# non-sense word associations in Text Mining

Tags: r, text, nlp, tokenize, text-mining

Hi， I ran this text analysis for word associations. However, the word associations do not make any sense. For example, I was interested in the association between "women" and other words. But the output provides non-sense word associations, such as "bagthey". Does anyone know where the problem is? I also attached my code below. I tried both running or not running the "Eliminate extra white spaces" codes.

Data could be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zaCrraYYNTXsrbfx0bG53pjxo9AMZu5M/view?usp=sharing

[image]

```
company <- read.csv("C:/Data.csv")


#### Set up data for analysis ####

# Create Corpus #To use the tm package we first transform the dataset to a corpus
corpus_review=Corpus(VectorSource(company$review))

# Convert all text to lowercase
corpus_review=tm_map(corpus_review, tolower)

# Stem words (i.e., to ensure no duplication of words for example work and working)
corpus_review=tm_map(corpus_review, stemDocument)

# Remove punctuations
corpus_review <- tm_map(corpus_review, removePunctuation, preserve_intra_word_contractions = TRUE, preserve_intra_word_dashes = TRUE,  ucp = TRUE)


# Convert the text to lower case
corpus_review <- tm_map(corpus_review, content_transformer(tolower))

# Remove numbers
corpus_review <- tm_map(corpus_review, removeNumbers)

# Remove english common stopwords
corpus_review <- tm_map(corpus_review, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

# Remove own words
corpus_review=tm_map(corpus_review, removeWords,c("also", "get","like", "made", "can", "im", "just","a", "I"))

# Eliminate extra white spaces
#corpus_review <- tm_map(corpus_review, stripWhitespace)


# Text stemming - which reduces words to their root form
corpus_review <- tm_map(corpus_review, stemDocument)


# Build a term-document matrix
TextDoc_dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus_review)
dtm_m <- as.matrix(TextDoc_dtm)

# Sort by deceasing value of frequency
dtm_v <- sort(rowSums(dtm_m),decreasing=TRUE)
dtm_d <- data.frame(word = names(dtm_v),freq=dtm_v)
head(dtm_d, 5)

#### Word Associations####

associations <- findAssocs(TextDoc_dtm, "women", 0.1)
associations_df <- list_vect2df(associations)[, 2:3]

ggplot(associations_df, aes(y = associations_df[, 1])) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = associations_df[, 2]), 
             data = associations_df, size = 3) + 
  ggtitle("Word Associations to 'the key word'") + 
  theme_gdocs()
```

Comment: Well, without hacking into your c drive and looking at your input data, I'd guess your input data has been poorly edited and you have no spaces at all or characters that aren't recognised as separators between two "sensible" words that are forming your "nonsense" words.  Or perhaps `stripWhitespace` or `removeWords` aren't behaving well...

Comment: @Limey, hi, I just updated the post and added the data link. The input data has spaces between words. Could you please take another look? Really appreciate it!

Comment: You have some issues with your text. sentences that are split with a point, but not a space. You will need to zoom into a few reviews that have words like you see in your plot. These occurrences are probably very low, like in 1 review. Once you located one, you can check what you need to do to clean up the results.